# How to set amazonSQSClient parameter on AWS-SQS Camel component

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I've got a bean

```
@Component
public class SqsClient {

    @Autowired
    private AWSCredentialsProvider customChain;

    @Value("my-region")
    private String region;

    private AmazonSQS sqsClient;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        sqsClient = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(customChain)
                .build();
    }

    public AmazonSQS getAmazonSQSClient() {
        return sqsClient;
    }
}
```

Also in my context I declared route

```
<route id="process.sqs.message">
    <from uri="aws-sqs://{{aws.sqs.queue}}?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient"/>
    <to url="bean:sqsQueueListener?method=processMessage(${body})"/>
</route>
```

But when I start the application I get the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: amazonSQSClient as there isn't a setter method with same type: 
java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS with value #sqsClient
```

Why it cannot set the `amazonSQSClient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, the `amazonSQSClient` parameter on the `aws-sqs` component must be a reference to a `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS` in the Camel Registry.

Add the `@Bean` annotation to your getter with the same name as you reference it in the `aws-sqs` endpoint:

```
@Bean(name = "sqsClient")
public AmazonSQS getAmazonSQSClient() {
    return sqsClient;
}
```

Comment: so basically I should use some class that extends `AmazonSQS`?

Comment: always forget about `@Bean` annotation